# Heroku yii2-app-basic not logging

Tags: logging, heroku, yii2

I'm trying to deploy mu application to heroku, but on the server, runtime directory is empty. Here is my log config:

```
    'log' => [                                                                                    
             //'traceLevel' => (YII_ENV_DEF) ? 3 : 0,
             'targets' => [
                 [
                     'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                     'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                 ],
                 [
                     'class' => 'yii\log\SyslogTarget',
                     'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                 ],
                 [
                     'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                     'levels' => ['error', 'warning', 'info'],
                     'logFile' => '@app/runtime/all.log',
                     'maxFileSize' => 1024 * 2,
                     'maxLogFiles' => 20, 
                 ],
             ],
         ],
```

Access right for runtime directory are 777.

Comment: I believe the default is `@runtime/logs/app.log` so are all sub-directories set to the same permission level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was/is that heroku file system is not synced across the instance of the app. In short, newer use file system to store data on heroku, use stderr for errors and something else for files.